# Windows Virtual Desktop Spring 2020 - Internal Server Error

Tags: windows, virtualization, desktop

I have a **WVD - Windows Virtual Desktop** setup using the Spring 2020 update.

I have setup a new DC, New domain, New o365, new AD connect.
I have setup a session host pool, application group and workspace.
My VM Pool is "Personal", "Direct" assigned.
My users are assigned to a "Desktop" application group.
I have two session hosts running Windows 10 connected to the New domain.

My problem is that I cannot assign any users to any VMs. I have tried via the portal and via Powershell 7 but both give me the same unhelpful error - "**InternalServerError**"

I can login locally to the VM within the network using the user accounts but cannot assign them individually to the VMs within WVD for remote access via the workspace.

Has anyone else got this or managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the `InternalServerError` message seems to come from Azure's back-end API (to which both the Azure portal and the Azure PowerShell talk); if *you* did something wrong, the message would (hopefully) be clearer about what your error was.

I'd raise a support ticket.